# Is it allowed to add a TXT record to a DNS query?

Tags: networking, dns

I know it's not standard, but is acceptable to add a TXT record to the 'Additional Records' section of a DNS **query** (not response)?

I've looked through the relevant RFCs:
https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181
and cannot find anything that explicitly forbids adding a TXT record to a DNS query.

If it is not explicitly forbidden, is it allowed? Will firewalls let the DNS query through?

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that forbids it, and if you do add such a record the resulting DNS query packet will still be well-formed according to the DNS wire format specification. Given that the most obvious *use* for a packet like that is to hide non-DNS traffic in DNS packets, I would not be surprised at all if many content-inspecting firewalls will block such packets.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to go with data exfiltration, nice write up here: https://community.infoblox.com/t5/Community-Blog/DNS-Data-Exfiltration-How-it-works/ba-p/3664